# create-react-app not producing public and src folders

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I initially started using CRA and it worked fine without any issues for about a week, however today I created a new react app and it neglects building the public and src folders. I have images below of what I see after I run "npx create-react-app my-app". I've tried "npm uninstall -g create-react-app" but that does not fix the issue.

CRA Issue Image 1

[image: CRA Issue Image 1]

CRA Issue Image 2

[image: CRA Issue Image 2]

CRA Issue Image 3

[image: CRA Issue Image 3]

[image: CRA Issue Image 4]

[image: CRA Issue Image 5]

Comment: can you post an entire screenshot of your terminal doing npx then in the same terminal once that cmd is finished type `cd my_app` and `ls`

Comment: Hello - that was the entire screenshot of the terminal after doing npx. It literally ends at "Done in XXXs". I added new picture as "CRA Issue Image 3"

Comment: Would you try that again? maybe in another directory `npx create-react-app my-app2`

Comment: Unfortunately same outcome. I really don't understand what's going on, I'm not getting an error message or anything. It's just not completing the process

Comment: No I was asking you take another screenshot of doing npx and the cding into the folder so the screenshot would have the output of npx + you going into the folder to look atthe files

Comment: Sorry about that - I just added the screenshots (4 and 5).

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: I did not end up solving it. Any help or suggestions would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your **command prompt** instead, and try opening your **resource monitor** and check if the status of **cmd.exe** changes to *Suspended* after running `npx create-react-app`. If it does, right click and choose *Resume Process*

Source: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8915